# powershell extract zip file to a shared folder

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract zip file that exists on a PC to another PC that has a shared folder.
I'm running this:

```
powershell Expand-Archive -Path C:\test.zip -DestinationPath \\TEST\TEST1 -Force
```

But get this error, any ideas ?

```
New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
At C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:315 char:32
+ ... eatedItem = New-Item -Path $DestinationPath -ItemType Directory -Conf ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\TEST\TEST1:String) [New-Item], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Comment: I do not seem to have any difficulty expanding into a UNC specified directory. What is your actual command line? Based on the error message, it appears that you are specifying th `\\iltlvvmsimr64\ELAD` directory.

Comment: Can confirm, as of PowerShell 5.1 at least `Expand-Archive -Path Archive.zip -Destination \\hostname\C$` works without issue. Are you certain the share name does not end in a `$`? Not sure if that might cause issues but I don't have an unhidden share to test with.

Comment: You may need to use (single) quotes around the paths because they may contain spaces of `$` sings that could be mis-interpreted by PowerShell as being variables.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it looks like this error is known to occur when there is a problem detected with the expected destination some of the files as structured within the zip some examples (this is distinct from files *already existing* which has a specific error attributed to this):

- Access is denied to part of the extraction path. In other words, a *nested* folder within the archive would extract to a folder you cannot write to.
- The filenames are too long, and exceeds 260 characters including the share path you are extracting to. This is not from the root of the remote server's local disk; this would be the path character count as the extraction process sees it.

  - This particular issue can actually be worked around from with *Explorer* but I don't know whether `Expand-Archive` supports the `LongPathsEnabled` registry attribute. To attempt to workaround this issue, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` in `regedit.exe` and set the DWORD `LongPathsEnabled = 1`, or set the same from PowerShell.

You can try adding `-Force` as a parameter which some have reported as resolving the issue, if this is caused by trying to write to a read-only location. However, it seems that this is resultant of an issue interacting with the filesystem when the path is otherwise well-formed.